# ASP.NET paging in masterpage opens in new window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a gridview inside the content panel of a page that references a master page. I have paging enabled in the gridview and when I click on page 2 to view the second page the grid is displayed in another window that pops up. From the point onwards a click on next page shows the data in the popped up window.

How do I force the gridview to show the data in the same page?
I'm using ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: I have tried that for more than 5 times and did'nt get that issue,... did you register any client script with your grid??

Comment: Hello Abdul. No I do not register any client script with the script. Do I have to do that?

Comment: no, i thought that you have registered something... anyway, i did'nt get that issue..